# why featured image option isn't showing in custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I have created a custom post type named as images but it isn't showing option of featured image in my wp-admin. I registered my custom post type in functions.php as

```
function my_custom_post_Images(){   
$labels2 = array(
'name'               => _x( 'Images', 'post type general name' ),
'singular_name'      => _x( 'Image', 'post type singular name' ),
'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Image' ),
'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Image' ),
'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Image' ),
'new_item'           => __( 'New Image' ),
'all_items'          => __( 'All Images' ),
'view_item'          => __( 'View Image' ),
'search_items'       => __( 'Search Images' ),
'not_found'          => __( 'No Images found' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Images found in the Trash' ),
'parent_item_colon'  => '',
'menu_name'          => 'Post Images');


 $args2 = array(
'labels'        => $labels2,
'description'   => 'Displays Images',
'public'        => true,
'menu_position' => 3,
'supports'      => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
'has_archive'   => true, );

    register_post_type( 'Images', $args2 );
      }
    add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_Images' );
```

Answer (score 0):

May be add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); is not included in your theme's 'after_setup_theme' action hook function.